# Is it possible to restrict git branches to a specific number of files changed

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, eslint

I am now working on a project which started growing and code reviews have become quite important. From the other hand, this is a small team and a single person is responsible for multiple activities. I have noticed, that the quality of the code reviews has started to decrease and I have the feeling that it is because of the big number of files changed in a change set. For that reason, I decided to incorporate an inner rule to not have more than 20 files changed in a branch. If you see you need to go bigger - branch out. Unfortunately, this rule does not seem to be considered by the developers and I decided to reach out for an advice on how can I restrict that on a source control level (Git, in our case). We are using GitLab as a sync point.

My main idea is to grow the master branch on a small steps that were well implemented, reviewed and tested instead of integrating huge changes.

**EDIT**: We also have eslint in the app (React app + Firebase Cloud functions).

Answer (score 1):

A noble goal, and a problem commonly encountered when working in larger projects. Alas, neither git nor GitLab offers a simple functionality to limit allowed branch (or merge request) size.

You can, however, use [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). In your case, you could script a server-side pre-receive hook that declines pushes if too many changes are to be pushed.